# Where can I find an interesting data set with 3 way interactions?

Tags: data-request

I am writing about moderation and interactions and would like a data set that has some interesting 3 way interactions.

Comment: Do you mean 3-way-interactions as in "requiring the introduction of triple interaction terms"? Would you prefer the data to be "interesting" in terms of it's underlying interpretation of the data or interesting in terms of most illustrative for understanding triple interactions?

Comment: I mean a data set where a three way interaction is important for understanding the data. Interesting - well, either one, really, but I guess I'd prefer the latter choice.  Thanks

Comment: Try to find in R package `datasets` .  These are the canonical datasets used for a illustrations. Also, you can usually find lots of examples of these datasets usage.